# Unable to get temp directory for .NET web site hosted in Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, azure

We're working on validating our Loupe service to run as an Azure App Service and have run into a showstopper we can't figure out.  Anything that attempts to resolve a temp directory fails with the exception:

```
    mscorlib : System.IO.IOException
    The directory name is invalid.
      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
      at System.IO.Path.InternalGetTempFileName(Boolean checkHost)
```

The stack trace has this within the .NET method for generating a temp file name.  This stack trace is common to pretty much all the areas we get the failure.  For a bit it seemed that if we forced the site to restart and/or forced the underlying App Service Plan to rescale it would go away until we next updated the site but no longer.

Since the only search results we could find said this error happens when impersonation is enabled and the user the site's impersonating doesn't have access to the IIS App Pool user's temp directory we've dug into that.  First, we can confirm from our logging that the thread is not impersonating at the time the failed request is made.  Second, just for fun we added this to the web.config to be doubly sure:

```xml
<system.web>        
    <identity impersonate="false"/>
</system.web>
```

All to no avail.  If this was a generic problem with Azure App Services then I would presume it would break many systems, so I have to conclude we've done something fascinating and wrong to cause it.

Comment: Do you get this error all the time or does it sometimes work properly?

Comment: At this point we can't get it to work at all any more, every time we call anything that needs a temp directory *boom*.  Previously once a process exhibited this behavior there was no coming back, but restarts occasionally got it working (for the life of the process).

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the exact answer you're looking for but it might help point you in the right direction.

I had similar issues a while back using the Azure App Services. I found that accessing the local file system was somewhat problematic. Sometimes it worked fine and other times it didn't.

Eventually, I discovered that when an Azure App Service is instantiated, it doesn't always use the same drive letters for the system behind it. In some cases, this can cause the environment variables to be blatantly incorrect. They "think" they are set properly, but that's not always the case.

Generating a temp filename will use that environment variable for the path and if it's set to C: but the machine has a D: drive instead, if will fail. The C: drive doesn't exist and therefore the path to the temp file can't exist either.

To identify if this is the problem, you need to enable RDP so you can log into it directly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-role-enable-remote-desktop

It's the only way I was able to eventually figure it out.

Comment: Oh, that's my fault. When I ran into this, I was using a Worker role. I don't recall if the App Services were a separate thing at the time & I assumed they were the same. I was just pointing at something similar that I ran into which might lead in the right direction. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Right - web/worker role instances would change drive letters. Web Apps are just going to use `d:\home\...`.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up the Kudu instance for your App Service Web App you'll be able to see what the local Temp directory is on the Managed VM underneath. You can access Kudu by going to "Advanced Tools" on the App Service blade in the Azure Portal, or by navigating to the *https://{web app name}.scm.azurewebsites.net* domain for your Web App.

Once in Kudu, click on Environment in the top navigation. The Temp directory is usually *D:\local\Temp* and that path is stored in the "TEMP" environment variable made accessible to your Web App.

Comment: Indeed and as expected, there is a temp directory - the problem is that calls made by my application that under the covers attempt to resolve the temp directory fail to do so (or fail to have access to the directory).

Comment: Looks like they've switched to C:\local\Temp now.